# CONTEXT struct doesn't contain Eip? C++

Tags: c++, winapi, struct

I'm trying to modify thread and the CONTEXT struct doesn't contain Eip.

```
HANDLE hThread;
CONTEXT ctx;
ctx.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_ALL;

DWORD processId = GetCurrentProcessId();
DWORD mainThreadId = GetMainThreadId(processId);

hThread = OpenThread((THREAD_GET_CONTEXT | THREAD_SET_CONTEXT | THREAD_SUSPEND_RESUME), FALSE, mainThreadId);
if (hThread)
{
    if (GetThreadContext(hThread, &ctx))
    {
        ???ctx.Eip??
    }
}
```

I don't understand why, despite it should. Thanks!

Comment: Which CONTEXT is it?

Comment: Processor architecture you're compiling to?

Comment: Risking a guess, you are compiling a 64-bit build. The instruction pointer is called *Rip* for x64. The structure is (obviously) processor architecture specific, as spelled out in the documentation for [CONTEXT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679284.aspx). Did you have a look at *WinNT.h*, as the documentation suggests?

Comment: Ah! Makes sense now, that's exactly why. Thanks! @IInspectable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [CONTEXT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679284.aspx) structure is processor architecture specific. It contains an *Eip* member, when compiling for x86 targets (preprocessor symbol `_M_IX86` defined). For x64 targets (preprocessor symbol `_M_AMD64` defined), the instruction pointer is stored in the *Rip* member.

Structure definitions for all supported processor architectures are defined in the *WinNT.h* header file of the Windows SDK.